# Convert object with single entry to array in Lodash

Tags: javascript, arrays, data-structures, mapping, lodash

I'm using lodash to transform a response from a GraphQL. What I've is the following structure:

```js
[[
  { nodes: [ {}, {} ] },
  { nodes: [ {}, {} ] },
  { nodes: [ {}, {}, {} ] },
  { nodes: [ {}, {}, {} ] },
  { nodes: [ {}, {} ] },
  { nodes: [ {}, {}, {} ] },
], [
  { nodes: [ {}, {} ] },
  { nodes: [ {}, {}, {} ] },
  { nodes: [ {}, {}, {} ] },
  { nodes: [ {}, {} ] },
  { nodes: [ {}, {} ] },
  { nodes: [ {}, {}, {} ] },
]]
```

But what I need is the following structure:

```js
[[
  [ {}, {} ],
  [ {}, {} ],
  [ {}, {}, {} ],
  [ {}, {}, {} ],
  [ {}, {} ],
  [ {}, {}, {} ],
], [
  [ {}, {} ],
  [ {}, {}, {} ],
  [ {}, {}, {} ],
  [ {}, {} ],
  [ {}, {} ],
  [ {}, {}, {} ],
]]
```

What I've is the following chain:

```js
_.chain(resp.data.data.projects.nodes)
.flatMap('ciVariables')
.value()
```

Any idea how to get the target structure using the chain in Lodash? I already tried to use `flatMap('ciVariables.nodes')`, but then all objects are in the top array.

Comment: Do you have one array or multiple arrays?

Comment: @Unmitigated In `ciVariables` there're two arrays and within these arrays there're objects with just one key (`nodes`) and the `nodes`-key is an array with multiple entries.

Comment: Is `ciVariables` an array of arrays or is it an object?

Comment: @Unmitigated It's an object: `ciVariables: { nodes: [Array] }`

Comment: Why at all is the OP looking for a lodash based solution when the language core offers a solution as simple as ... `array.map(nodeList => nodeList.map(({ nodes }) => nodes));`?

Comment: @PeterSeliger OP is a time traveler from 2005

Comment: @Nrgyzer ... please update your example code to a valid and minimal useful data-structure in order to not confuse the audience about which correct approach to choose. Especially `[Object]` most probably is nothing which actually is part of the data-structure. The posted structure looks like being copy-pasted from a console log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use double map.

First we loop through the outer array, for each array inside we return the value of nodes property.

```js
const before = [[
  { nodes: [ {}, {} ] },
  { nodes: [ {}, {} ] },
  { nodes: [ {}, {}, {} ] },
  { nodes: [ {}, {}, {} ] },
  { nodes: [ {}, {} ] },
  { nodes: [ {}, {}, {} ] },
], [
  { nodes: [ {}, {} ] },
  { nodes: [ {}, {}, {} ] },
  { nodes: [ {}, {}, {} ] },
  { nodes: [ {}, {} ] },
  { nodes: [ {}, {} ] },
  { nodes: [ {}, {}, {} ] },
]]

const after = before.map(arr => {
    return arr.map(object => {
    return object.nodes
  })
})

console.log(after)
```

You can also make it into a one-liner

```
const after = before.map(arr => arr.map(object => object.nodes))
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const array = [
  { nodes: [ [Object], [Object] ] },
  { nodes: [ [Object], [Object] ] },
  { nodes: [ [Object], [Object] ] },
  { nodes: [ [Object], [Object] ] },
  { nodes: [ [Object], [Object] ] },
  { nodes: [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ] },
  { nodes: [ [Object], [Object] ] },
  { nodes: [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ] },
  { nodes: [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ] },
  { nodes: [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ] },
  { nodes: [ [Object], [Object] ] },
  { nodes: [ [Object], [Object] ] },
  { nodes: [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ] },
  { nodes: [ [Object], [Object] ] }
]

const result = _.chain(array)
  .map(function(o) {
    return o.nodes
  })
  .value();

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: `array` is an array of (according to the OP just 2) arrays where the inner arrays have the structure of the above code example. The OP did omit the most outer brackets and the comma in between the 2 first level nested arrays.

Answer (score 0):

From one of my above comments which does suggest a nested entirely [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) based solution ...

> *"Why at all is the OP looking for a *lodash* based solution when the language core offers a solution as simple as ... `array.map(nodeList => nodeList.map(({ nodes }) => nodes));`?"*

```js
const responseData = [[
  { nodes: [ {}, {} ] },
  { nodes: [ {}, {}, {} ] },
  { nodes: [ {}, {}, {} ] },
], [
  { nodes: [ {}, {} ] },
  { nodes: [ {}, {} ] },
  { nodes: [ {}, {}, {} ] },
]];

console.log({ responseData });

const sanitizedData = responseData
  .map(listOfCiVariableItems =>
    listOfCiVariableItems
      .map(({ nodes }) => nodes)
  );

console.log({ sanitizedData });
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```